# Entangling Exhalation + Slow Breath

Tags: dnd-3.5e

We are playing in a high-level message-board campaign, and my friend have a Rogue/Dragonfire Adept (level 2/level 16). We are currently facing two adult white dragons. My friend is arborn, hidden & invisible, and is behind an equally invisible, airborn white (we both can see invisible - I'm playing a warlock). Now, he first plan to do an entangling exhalation (fire breath) on the dragon, then follow it up with a slow breath on the next round. Now, dragons are by nature fast flyers, but they are not very agile in the air. If he hit both attacks (and he should, as he have a flight speed of 80, perfect manueverability), that should cause the dragon to slow down to a quarter of its normal speed.

My question is: Will the dragon still be able to fly while it's under both breath effects? I would figure gliding would be the best it could hope to do, but I would like to hear more expert views than my own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dragon will fall.

An [Adult White Dragon](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dragonTrue.htm#whiteDragon) has [Poor Maneuverability](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/movement.htm#movingInThreeDimensions). One of the restrictions of Poor Maneuverability is that the creature must maintain a Minimum Forward Speed.

> **Minimum Forward Speed**
>
> If a flying creature fails to maintain its minimum forward speed, it must land at the end of its movement. If it is too high above the ground to land, it falls...

The dragon must thus move 100' (half its fly speed) each round if it is to remain aloft.

Now, the dragon will be both slowed (similar to the [Slow](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/slow.htm) spell) and [Entangled](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#entangled). These conditions stack:

> **Hampered Movement**
>
> Difficult terrain, obstacles, or poor visibility can hamper movement. When movement is hampered, each square moved into usually counts as two squares, effectively reducing the distance that a character can cover in a move.
>
> If more than one condition applies, multiply together all additional costs that apply. (This is a specific exception to the normal rule for doubling)

So the dragon's fly speed is reduced to 200'/(2*2) = 50'. He can not take more than one move action per round (due to the Slow effect), he can not run or charge (due to the Entanglement), and thus can not, without additional help, maintain his Minimum Forward Speed, and falls.